# Daylight saving time in java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

please see if you can tell me how to handle the DST issue in my case.

first, my application is a logistic system and it is for global user,so it involves timezone problem,i will handle it as following when set user local date of booking:

1.when user login application,we could get user's timezone according to login IP,but is is just an offset (i don't remember the term of this stuff) e.g "GMT+08"(BeiJing) or "GMT-06"(Chicago) .

2.before user save booking ,we need to set booking local date,as i can't get user local date direct .so i will get the server date first(in my case,it is BeiJing time),then calculate local date according to server date and user timezone,e.g if user timezone is "GMT-08",server date is 2013-08-29 17:45:00. server timezone is "GMT+08",then i will use server date-8-8 and the result will be 2013-08-29 01:45:00.but as i don't consider the DST,the calculated local date will be difference from the actual date.e.g now in San Francisco,the actual local date will be earlier one hour than the result that i calculated using this way,

i find the java TimeZone have already considered the DST problem,but i need to provide "location" name(e.g US/Alaska,Pacific/Apia) when construct TimeZone . while in my case, what i can get is just the offset.so can you tell me how to fix the DST issue in my case?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

An offset is the number hours-minutes-seconds from [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (GMT) that is represented by a certain date-time value. West coast is -08:00 (ignoring [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) nonsense), meaning 8 hours behind UTC.

Beware that java.time in its initial release has a small bug where it fails to handle an offset of just hours (such as `+08`) without minutes (such as `+08:00`).

A [time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

Use proper [time zone names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (mostly continent slash city). Avoid the 3 or 4 letter codes, such as EST, which are neither standardized nor unique.

A `java.util.Date` has no time zone, while a Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) does.

To get a web browser's time zone, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/determining-a-web-users-time-zone). But often, this does not work well. As you've probably seen, many web sites ask the user to choose a time zone.

Your exact use-case is confusing. Generally the best approach is to use date-time values for UTC, then adjust to user's local time as needed. Usually best for your software to work and store date-times as UTC. Then present a local date-time adjusted to suit the user. In other words, think globally (UTC), present locally (local time zone adjusted).

Usually sysadmins keep their server computers set to UTC (no time zone offset). If your OS (like Mac OS X) does not offer UTC, then use `Reykjavik` as Iceland uses UTC year-round without any Daylight Saving Time. Likewise, database engines almost always convert date-time values to UTC for storage.

Joda-Time does offer a LocalDate class for when you truly do not care about time zone or time. But often it is better to use a date-time (a DateTime instance), and format for a date-only string as needed.

Example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneChina = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Shanghai" );
DateTime dateTimeChina = new DateTime( 2013, 8, 29, 17, 45, 00, timeZoneChina );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeChina.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
DateTime dateTimeParis = dateTimeChina.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) );

DateTimeZone timeZoneUsWestCoast = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Los_Angeles" );
DateTime dateTimeUnitedStatesWestCoast = dateTimeChina.withZone( timeZoneUsWestCoast );

DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
String outputDateOnlyForUnitedStatesWestCoast = formatter.withZone( timeZoneUsWestCoast ).print( dateTimeUtc );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeChina: " + dateTimeChina );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeParis: " + dateTimeParis );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUnitedStatesWestCoast: " + dateTimeUnitedStatesWestCoast );
System.out.println( "outputDateOnlyForUnitedStatesWestCoast: " + outputDateOnlyForUnitedStatesWestCoast );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeChina: 2013-08-29T17:45:00.000+08:00
dateTimeUtc: 2013-08-29T09:45:00.000Z
dateTimeParis: 2013-08-29T11:45:00.000+02:00
dateTimeUnitedStatesWestCoast: 2013-08-29T02:45:00.000-07:00
outputDateOnlyForUnitedStatesWestCoast: 2013-08-29
```

### *java.time*

Similar code in *java.time*.

Current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC.
```

Adjust into a time zone for Chicago area, yielding a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId zChicago = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtChicago = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Adjust into China time zone.

```
ZoneId zShanghai = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Shanghai" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtShanghai = zdtChicago.withZoneSameInstant( zChicago ) ;
```

All three objects (`instant`, `zdtChicago`, and `zdtShanghai`) represent the same moment, the same point on the timeline. Simultaneous, but seen through various wall-clock times.

Apparently you want just the date portion for some purpose, without the time-of-day and without time zone. For that extract a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = zdtChicago.toLocalDate() ;
```

Of course that may be a different date than returned by `zdtShanghai.toLocalDate()`.

You may need to construct a specific moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtShanghai = ZonedDateTime.of( 2013, 8, 29, 17, 45, 0, 0 , zShanghai ) ;
```

### Location and time zone

You said:

> i need to provide "location" name

Location has nothing to do with time zone. A businessperson from Québec might want to see a particular schedule in `America/Montreal` zone while physically traveling in Tokyo Japan.

You can ask the user’s web browser or local JVM for its current default time zone. But ultimately, if critical, you must confirm the desired/expected time zone with the user.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3):

It's a common source of headache

1. In my experience, location by IP address is not always reliable, for example when people are using corporate VPNs.
2. You are correct, region-based time zones ("Europe/Paris", "CET") are preferable for properly handling DST.

I solved a similar problem with the following approach :
You associate a precise timezone to each user in your server-side database. When user fills a booking form you display a TZ selector, pre-filled with his default TZ. So he can double check it (IMHO much safer than guessing by IP) and on server side, Dates can be safely converted from local to server time and back.

Answer (score 1):

Joda time might be able to solve your problem:

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html

Comment: Yes,i heard joda is a very powerful tool,but can you tell me more specific stuff?e.g how to use joda process my case?